# how to retrieve image from database which define in <ul> tag in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

i want retrieve images which present in database ,image tag iam given in  tag so that's why iam not getting how will i do 
here is my aspx code

```
 <div id="mask-gallery">
      <ul id="gallery" runat="server">
        <li>
          <img src="/images/projects/<%# Eval("Top_Image")%>" width="981" height="279" title="hello" alt="hello"/></li>
          <asp:Image ID="imgTop" ImageUrl='/images/Projects/<%# Eval("Top_Image") %>' runat="server" width="981" height="279" AlternateText="hello" />
       </ul>
    </div>
```

here my cs code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Constr"]);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetImageData();
            }
        }
        protected void GetImageData()
        {
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id_Project", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
            param[0].Value = lblid.Text.ToString().Trim();

            SqlCommand Cmdd = new SqlCommand("tpRetrieve_Project_Master_Top_Image", con);
            Cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Cmdd.Parameters.Add(param[0]);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader drr = Cmdd.ExecuteReader();


            if (drr.HasRows)
            {
                while (drr.Read())
                {
                    hd_Show_In_Top.Value = drr["Show_In_Top"].ToString().Trim();
                    if (hd_Show_In_Top.Value == "Yes")
                    {
                        hd_thumbnail.Value = drr["Top_Image"].ToString().Trim();
                        lblbdescription.Text = drr["Description"].ToString().Trim();
                        lblbprojecttype.Text = drr["Project_type"].ToString().Trim();
                        // lblrotation.Text = lblrotation.Text + "<a href='/about-us/people.aspx'><img class='cloudcarousel'  src='/images/AboutUsTopImages/" + hd_thumbnail..Value.ToString().Trim() + " '/></a>";
                    }
                }
            }

            drr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What is the column type of Top_Image?

Answer (score 2):

One possible (and very common actually) approach is to create an HttpHandler that will get the image from the database and write it to the response. Check out [this link](http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/images/Displaying_images_in_ASPNET_using_HttpHandlers_92.aspx) to see a working example.

Answer (score 0):

if you storing the image name with the extention in the database you can do something like this

```
var x = datasource();//your datasource which contains the imagefile

<img src='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/projects/") + x.imageFile + "' alt='Test' />
```

Comment: This will only work if you get the filename from the database, but the file itself is on the filesystem (in that ~/images/projects folder). Not if the image itself is in the database.

Comment: i have cs code also where i define sp and trying to retrieve image for there... i want image retrieve from <ul> tag basis

Comment: could you tell us what type of field you using to store the image. Are you saving image as image name + extention or are you using binary?

Comment: iam saving image as image name with it's extension

Comment: then above mention way should work. put a breakpoint in  hd_thumbnail.Value = drr["Top_Image"].ToString().Trim()  and what is the value its getting

Answer (score 0):

If `Top_Image` contains the filename.ext (`sample.jpeg`) then you should try this,

```
<img runat="server"
     src='<%# Eval("Top_Image","~/images/projects/{0}") %>'
     width="981" 
     height="279" 
     title="hello" 
     alt="hello"/>
    </li>
<asp:Image ID="imgTop" 
        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Top_Image","~/images/Projects/{0}") %>'
        runat="server" 
        width="981" 
        height="279" 
AlternateText="hello" />
```

If you are not binding the DataSource then no need to use `Eval()` method. You may assign ImageUrl property in code behind.

```
if (drr.Read())
  {
    hd_Show_In_Top.Value = drr["Show_In_Top"].ToString().Trim();
    if (hd_Show_In_Top.Value == "Yes")
    {
       imgTop.ImageUrl="~/images/Projects/" +drr["Top_Image"].ToString().Trim();
       ....
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Aties - I guess you are retrieving a single row  and you are not using GridView or Datalist. Isn't it?

Comment: @Aties - Please check the location of image files (whether the images/projects folder is present or not) and content of "Top_Image" field.

Comment: dude Project folder present and Field also i check it is right